# BarButton Items are getting events while clicking on navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7

I am adding custom back button to navigation bar(custom navigation controller) like this:-

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goback.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBackButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];//same as image width and height
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

When I click close to bar button items(both left and right) the bar buttons are getting touch events.

I would like to prevent this weird behavior.

I am developing app for `iOS7`.

Comment: y u go for custom instead of the existing.....?

Answer (score 0):

I tried adjusting the width property of the barButtonItem and no luck.

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.width = 32;
```

but I have an interesting solution for you,

You can use two buttons in your custom view, one that implements that method you want, and other a dummy button

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBackButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];//same as image width and height

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

UIButton *dummyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

UIBarButtonItem *dummyBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:dummyButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[barButton,dummyBarButton];
```

Comment: Thanks ManicMonkOnMac for your quick reply. I tried the approach suggested by you.Its working fine. I do not think this approach is fine because we have to create dummy buttons for both left and right bar button items to prevent the issue.

Comment: you might have to create dummy buttons, but I can't think of any other solution, I tried adjusting the widths etc. Do let me know if you find a better solution. It's only three lines of additional code.